# Escaping special characters in custom submit handler redirect URL?

Tags: redirection, forms

My submit handler contains a redirect to a URL formatted thus:

```
mysite.com/node/123/edit?step=step_2
```

and my problem is that it's appearing in the browser bar as:

```
mysite.com/node/123/edit%3Fstep%3Dstep=step_2
```

which messes up my redirect.

How do I escape the characters "=" and "?" for use in a URL for redirection from a custom submit handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an array as the value for `$form_state['redirect']`, it will eventually be passed to [`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7). So you can use the same options as for that function to build up a structured query string:

```
$path = 'node/' . $nid . '/edit';
$query = array('step' => 'step_2');
$form_state['redirect'] = array($path, array('query' => $query));
```

There's more explanation in the documentation for the [`drupal_redirect_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7) function.